# How can I analyse the performance of a page type in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

On our eCommerce site, the job of the category page is to move the customer on to the product page. Then the job of the product page is to get the user to add a product to their basket.

I have set up an Add To Basket event, which is working nicely, but I am stuck with how to analyse the category page.

We have hundreds of products so all of the URL's are different.

Ideally, Id like to be able to produce a table like this.

```
|______CATEGORY_PAGE_______|__PROCEEDED_TO_PRODUCT_PAGE_|
|    /womens/dresses       |            34%             |
|    /womens/jewellery     |            39%             |
|    /mens/jackets         |            28%             |
_________________________________________________________
```

I am tracking visits to the category pagetype and product pagetype as a custom variable but I just don't know how to report on it.